# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in /www/application/controllers/Admin.php on line 586

Tags: php, sql

подскажите как обойти такой запрос, код делали давно, база разрослась, вывод не работает виснет,
может выводить частями

```
$this->content['items'] = $this->db->get('autos')->result();
```

код не помещается вот линк
https://fex.net/ru/s/szpked4

Answer (score 0):

Интерпретатор вызывает методы последовательно. Ваш способ вызова методов также называется "цепочка вызовов".
Условиям работы такой цепочки, состоит в возврате методом объекта (в частности `this`).

В вашем случае `$this->db->get('autos')` вместо `this` или объекта возвращает другой тип данных (Возможно `false`). Могу предположить, что функция get - не находит нужную таблицу.

Чтобы отладить код, посмотрите, что вернет Вам `$this->db->get('autos')`. Это можно сделать так:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($this->db->get('autos'));
echo '</pre>';
```

В случае, если вернет не объект или объект не содержащий result(), Вам придется искать ошибку именно в методе `get()`